# Tables in Data Modeler's Browser, not showing in Oracle Connection

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I created an entity-relationship diagram (logical model) and engineered it to a relational model.
The tables were generated. Now I need to use them from the connection XE as you see in the picture.

[image]

The tables I made can only be seen on the data modeler design view in the "Browser", how do I get them on the connection "XE" to generate data dictionary, etc?

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities:

1. you just need to expand the tables item in the tree to see your tables
2. You are looking in the wrong schema/user - go down to Other Users, and find the schema those tables belong to
3. The tables do not exist in the current database

If #3 is the issue, you would need to create them, possibly using the information in your Data Model - that is, you can generate the DDL/SQL scripts for those tables.

Then taking those scripts, run them while connected to the appropriate database/schema.

*Disclaimer: I'm an Oracle employee and the product manager for these tools.*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I copy pasted the generated DDL into the worksheet and created the tables and it worked!